# Use FME to expose each feature from feature class

Tags: shapefile, file-geodatabase, fme-form, split-by-attribute

I have a feature class in a geodatabase which usually has between 1-300 features.
I would like to use FME to expose each feature and create an individual shapefile for each, based on an attribute.

For example, my dataset may look like this:

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Ocean |
| 2 | Road |
| 3 | City |
| 4 | Town |

I would like to create from this table, 4 shapefiles, based on the attribute "ID"

This can be achieved in ArcMap by selecting the feature from the feature class, and exporting it as a shapefile. However, I would like to find an automated way to do this in FME.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term you are looking for in FME is "Fanout".

I would advise to use a FeatureWriter, this works more intuitive that a classic writer when you want to use attribute values for filenames.